# String to int bad output Nasm

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, nasm

I create funtion to change string to int, but output result is bad.
For example for `character db "1234" , 0`, I have output `11211231234` instead of `1234`. Maybe someone know where I do mistake. This is my code

```
%include "asm64_io.inc"

segment .data
character db "1234" , 0

segment .bss

segment .text

global asm_main
asm_main:
 enter 0,0 


mov rdx, character
call change_string_to_int
ret

change_string_to_int:
mov rcx, 0 ; licznik
mov rax, 0

_loop:
mov bl, [rdx + rcx]
test bl, bl
je _ex
sub bl, '0'
imul rax, 10
add rax, rbx
call print_int
inc rcx
jmp _loop



_ex:
mov rax, 0 
leave
ret
```

Comment: And if you clear `rbx` before the loop?

Comment: Or simply use `movzx ebx, byte [rdx + rcx]`.  The loop looks correct to me, with that change.

Comment: BTW, never use the ENTER instruction; it's really slow, even with `0,0`.  Just do the push/mov manually, like compilers do with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`.  LEAVE is ok, though.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm to convert from string to numeric requires two things :

- The string characters must be processed from right to left (starting at the least significant digit).
- Multiply each character by sequencial powers of 10 (1, 10, 100, 1000).

Here is your code with the necessary changes, I added variable `number` to store the final result and changed some registers, comments will help you to understand :

```
%include "asm64_io.inc"

segment .data
character db "1234" , 0
number    dq 0            ;◄■■■ FINAL RESULT (THE NUMBER).

segment .bss

segment .text

global asm_main
asm_main:
 enter 0,0 

mov rbx, character        ;◄■■■ RBX BECAUSE RDX WILL BE LOST AFTER MUL. 
mov rcx, 3                ;◄■■■ LENGTH OF "CHARACTER" - 1 (LOOP COUNTER).
call change_string_to_int
;▼ DISPLAY RESULT.
  mov rax, number
  call print_int
ret

change_string_to_int:
mov rdi, 1                 ;◄■■■ POWER OF 10 (10^0=1). 

_loop:
;▼ GET CURRENT CHAR.                
  xor rdx, rdx             ;◄■■■ CLEAR RDX, SO RDX=DL.
  mov dl, [rbx + rcx]      ;◄■■■ GET CHARACTER FROM RIGHT TO LEFT.
  sub dl, '0'              ;◄■■■ CONVERT CHAR TO DIGIT.
;▼ MUTIPLY DIGIT BY CURRENT POWER OF 10.
  mov rax, rdi             ;◄■■■ RAX = CURRENT POWER OF 10.
  mul rdx                  ;◄■■■ DIGIT * POWER OF 10.
  add number, rax          ;◄■■■ ACCUMULATE RESULT (DISCARD RDX).
;▼ CALCULATE NEXT POWER OF 10.
  mov rax, rdi             ;◄■■■ RAX = CURRENT POWER OF 10.
  mov rdi, 10
  mul rdi                  ;◄■■■ RAX * 10.
  mov rdi, rax             ;◄■■■ RDI = NEXT POWER OF 10.
;▼ CHECK IF LOOP REPEATS.
  dec rcx
  cmp rcx, 0
  jge _loop                ;◄■■■ IF RCX>=0 REPEAT.
mov rax, 0 
leave
ret
```

I display the number after `call change_string_to_int` (I guess `print_int` takes the number from `rax`).

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to process right to left, and do `total = total*10 + digit;` every iteration?  That's what the OP is trying to do, I think.